# Inconsistency caused by reflexive property

Tags: owl

The following ontology is inconsistent. Can you explain why?

```
:Ingredient    a                   owl:Class.

:Car           a                   owl:Class;
               owl:disjointWith    :Ingredient.

:MyCar         a                   :Car.

:Cheese        a                   :Ingredient.
:Milk          a                   :Ingredient.

:containsIngredient   a            owl:ReflexiveObjectProperty, owl:TransitiveObjectProperty;
                      rdfs:domain  :Ingredient;
                      rdfs:range   :Ingredient;

:Cheese        :containsIngredient :Milk.
```

The reasoner is inferring that `:MyCar    :containsIngredient    :MyCar`
which means that `:MyCar    a    :Ingredient`
and since `:MyCar     a      :Car`   and `:Car    :disjointWith    :Ingredient`, my ontology is inconsistent.

The question is: why is the reflexive property `:containsIngredient` true for `:MyCar`, although it has `:Ingredient` as range and domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently an `owl:ReflexiveObjectProperty` applies to all things (`owl:Thing`) regardless of the domain and range of the property. By setting a `rdfs:domain` and a `rdfs:range` to the property, you are implicitly asserting that all `owl:Thing` individuals are also individuals of the range and domain classes. In my opinion this renders the `owl:ReflexiveObjectPropery` useless.

What I should have done in the ontology above is to make `:Ingredient` equivalent to `containsIngredient Self` (Protégé class expression syntax), instead of using `owl:ReflexiveObject` property which ignores the domain and range of the property.

Comment: i dont think this is the answer, as the issue exists . i have the same issue that a reflexive property is applied to all individual even if i define domain and range that cause inconsistency